# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm  trying to get my discord javascript discord bot to send me a dm using id but it keeps saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Any idea?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const{prefix,token} = require('./config.json');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Ready!`);
});

bot.on('message', message => {
  let e = message.content.split(" ");

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}help`))
  {
    if (message.channel.type == "dm")
    {
      message.author.send("use !send");

    }

  } 

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}send`))
  {
    if (message.channel.type == "dm")
    {
      try{
      message.author.send("Message sent");
      message.client.users.get("266928832726xxxxxxx").send("someMessage");
    }catch(e){console.log("[ERROR]",e)}
    }

  } 

})

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: `message.author` is undefined.

Comment: `console.log(message)` and check if you get `author` with `message` value in it.

Comment: @zlotte , oh found the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you have to do in order to know what is the problem with `send` is, is to at first `console.log(message)` and check if you get the value called `author` and then check if `author` has value or method called `send`.

Answer (score 0):

You const your client as bot `const bot = new Discord.Client();`

And try get members as  `message.client.users.get("266928832726xxxxxxx")`
Message dont have property `client.users`  so use `bot.users.get()`

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  let e = message.content.split(" ");

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}help`)){
    if (message.channel.type == "dm"){
      message.author.send("use !send");
    }
  }

  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}send`)){
    if (message.channel.type == "dm"){
      message.author.send("Message sent");
      bot.users.get("266928832726xxxxxxx").send("someMessage").catch(console.error);
    }
  } 
})
```